# How can I turn on/off cache L1 for Thrust's algorithms?

Tags: caching, gpu, thrust

How can I switch between cudaFuncCachePreferShared/cudaFuncCachePreferL1 for Thrust algorithms, an example turn off for sort?

PS And an additional if you know, how to specify compilation flag in MS VS 2010 to turn off L1 cache in cuda, where must i write (-Xptxas -dlcm=cg)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `cudaFuncSetCacheConfig` runtime function to set your preference for L1 cache or shared memory.

Comment: `cudaFuncSetCacheConfig` doesn't turn off L1 cached fetches, it selects between 16/48kb and 48/16kb L1 cache/shared memory split. Not all the same thing.

Comment: He specifically asked about cudaFuncCachePreferShared. So I believe it to be relevant.